# Get undefined value from props on onClick event meanwhile the whole props are displaying well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm stuck getting undefined value when clicking on Answers "buttons". It has to console.log the id of this button which was generated by nanoid().

Questions.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import QuestionSet from "./QuestionSet";
import Answers from "./Answers";

export default function Questions() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=12&difficulty=easy&type=multiple"
    )
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(
            `This is an HTTP error: The status is ${response.status}`
          );
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((actualData) => {
        setData(actualData.results);
        setError(null);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err.message);
        setData(null);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  const listOfQuestions = data.map((item) => {
    const allAnswers = [
      { id: nanoid(), isCorrect: false, answer: item.incorrect_answers[0] },
      { id: nanoid(), isCorrect: false, answer: item.incorrect_answers[1] },
      { id: nanoid(), isCorrect: false, answer: item.incorrect_answers[2] },
      { id: nanoid(), isCorrect: true, answer: item.correct_answer },
    ];
    return {
      id: nanoid(),
      question: item.question,
      answers: allAnswers,
    };
  });

  function holdAnswer(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }

  const questionElm = listOfQuestions.map((question, index, i) => {
    return (
      <section key={index}>
        <QuestionSet question={question.question} key={question.id} />
        <Answers
          answers={question.answers}
          isChosen={question.isChosen}
          id={question.answers.id}
          holdAnswer={() => holdAnswer(question.answers.id)}
        />
      </section>
    );
  });

  return (
    <main className="quest-box">
      <section className="quest-content">{questionElm}</section>

      <button className="answer-btn">Check Answers</button>
      {loading && <div>Loading data...</div>}
      {error && <div>{`There is a problem fetchning data = ${error}`}</div>}
    </main>
  );
}
```

QuestionSet.js (component)

```
export default function QuestionSet(props) {
  return (
    <section className="quest" key={props.id}>
      <p>{props.question}</p>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Answers.js (component)

```
export default function Answers(props) {
  const styles = {
    backgroundColor: props.isChosen ? "#D6DBF5" : "transparent",
  };

  return (
    <section className="answer-container">
      
      <div
        className="answer-div"
        style={styles}
        id={props.answers[3].id}
        onClick={props.holdAnswer}
      >
        <p>{props.answers[3].answer}</p>
      </div>
      <div
        className="answer-div"
        style={styles}
        id={props.answers[1].id}
        onClick={props.holdAnswer}
      >
        <p>{props.answers[1].answer}</p>
      </div>
      <div
        className="answer-div"
        style={styles}
        id={props.answers[2].id}
        onClick={props.holdAnswer}
      >
        <p>{props.answers[2].answer}</p>
      </div>
      <div
        className="answer-div"
        style={styles}
        id={props.answers[0].id}
        onClick={props.holdAnswer}
      >
        <p>{props.answers[0].answer}</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Other props are displayed well such as questions and answer text. Also, I tested if the id of questions will be displaying and it works, but not the ids of the answers.
Why does it happen? Why does the part of `allAnswers` array are showing but the part with ids doesn't? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a few things wrong.

1. There is no `question.answers.id` it is an array, what you want is `question.answers[0].id`
2. Even with 1 sorted out, the way you handle the click is wrong, you need to just pass the function down to the child component, and let the child component handle it by itself

This is how your code will look like

Questions.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import QuestionSet from "./QuestionSet";
import Answers from "./Answers";

export default function Questions() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=12&difficulty=easy&type=multiple"
    )
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(
            `This is an HTTP error: The status is ${response.status}`
          );
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((actualData) => {
        setData(actualData.results);
        setError(null);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err.message);
        setData(null);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  const listOfQuestions = data.map((item) => {
    const allAnswers = [
      { id: nanoid(), isCorrect: false, answer: item.incorrect_answers[0] },
      { id: nanoid(), isCorrect: false, answer: item.incorrect_answers[1] },
      { id: nanoid(), isCorrect: false, answer: item.incorrect_answers[2] },
      { id: nanoid(), isCorrect: true, answer: item.correct_answer }
    ];
    return {
      id: nanoid(),
      question: item.question,
      answers: allAnswers
    };
  });

  function holdAnswer(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }

  const questionElm = listOfQuestions.map((question, index, i) => {
    return (
      <section key={index}>
        <QuestionSet question={question.question} key={question.id} />
        <Answers
          answers={question.answers}
          isChosen={question.isChosen}
          holdAnswer={holdAnswer}
        />
      </section>
    );
  });

  return (
    <main className="quest-box">
      <section className="quest-content">{questionElm}</section>

      <button className="answer-btn">Check Answers</button>
      {loading && <div>Loading data...</div>}
      {error && <div>{`There is a problem fetchning data = ${error}`}</div>}
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answers.js

```
export default function Answers(props) {
  console.log(props);
  const styles = {
    backgroundColor: props.isChosen ? "#D6DBF5" : "transparent"
  };

  return (
    <section className="answer-container">
      <div
        className="answer-div"
        style={styles}
        id={props.answers[3].id}
        onClick={() => props.holdAnswer(props.answers[3].id)}
      >
        <p>{props.answers[3].answer}</p>
      </div>
      <div
        className="answer-div"
        style={styles}
        id={props.answers[1].id}
        onClick={() => props.holdAnswer(props.answers[3].id)}
      >
        <p>{props.answers[1].answer}</p>
      </div>
      <div
        className="answer-div"
        style={styles}
        id={props.answers[2].id}
        onClick={() => props.holdAnswer(props.answers[3].id)}
      >
        <p>{props.answers[2].answer}</p>
      </div>
      <div
        className="answer-div"
        style={styles}
        id={props.answers[0].id}
        onClick={() => props.holdAnswer(props.answers[3].id)}
      >
        <p>{props.answers[0].answer}</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Here is a working solution

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-silence-tg43w0?file=/src/Answers.js:0-1116

Just to mention, there are a few optimization to be done for the code, but since it doesn't affect the question, I left it out, we can pick that off in the comment section

Comment: Hey! :) Thank you very much for the answer! It works now as I wished.

Comment: Glad it worked, @lsokol you can actually convert the answer component into a map with keys to reduce the code and also accommodate questions with more or less answers. I can update my solution to that if you want it.

BTW upvote the solution if you found it helpful.

Comment: If you can please show me what do you mean. Do you mean to map answers inside jsx in Answers component? 
I upvote it but since I'm a newbie here it says I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but it also says that saves my feedback :)